Replacing a 2-pole Quad Circuit Breaker
Can a 2-P Quad Breaker (20/30/30/20, with inside common trip) be replaced with a 1-P 20A breaker, a 2-P 30A breaker (common trip) and another 1-P 20A breaker?

Generally speaking, yes. But the key question is "why"? For example, you may need common shutoff (whether you have it right now or not) for the outer 20s, and doing that on standard size breakers is different than on a half-size quad. Picture of the panel and description of the circuits would help.

Click edit and then the mountain icon

You need to check what the outside breakers are feeding. If they are two unrelated circuits with separate neutrals, you can rearrange at will. If they share a neutral, you need to make sure the new breakers are on opposite legs of your service.

Yes, if you have the physical space in the panel for full size breakers. Beware MWBCs (shared neutral) throughout the panel, as moving 120V breakers can unexpectedly break up a MWBC.  MWBC pairs must be handle-tied.

You wrote “inside common trip” implying that the current 20 amp mini breakers are not common trip. Assuming this is correct, then yes, you can substitute the 240 volt 30 amp breaker and two 120 volt 20 amp breakers. This is functionally equivalent to what you have now. In fact, it is slightly better in that you can use 120 volt arc-fault or GFCI breakers if needed.
